# How to remove bathroom sink water supply hose in tight space

Tags: plumbing, sink

I'm attempting to change out a leaky water supply hose on my bathroom sink. Unfortunately, while I was able to disconnect the hose from the water shut off valve, none of my tools are small enough to disconnect the portion connected to the faucet. Looking online, the recommendation seems to be to use a basin wrench but I bought one and it doesn't fit in the tight space.

[image: View from under sink]

Anyone know how I can unscrew the hose from the top where it connects to the sink?

It appears like this person had a similar problem: [How can I fasten nuts in narrow places when installing a faucet?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/61941/how-can-i-fasten-nuts-in-narrow-places-when-installing-a-faucet)

But I was unclear what the solution was in that case.

Edit 1: To clarify, sink is undermounted

Edit 2: Photo of Top

[image: Top of Bathroom Sink]

Edit 3: Faucet removed. Thanks for help so far. However, even with the faucet removed, I still cannot seem to remove the hose. Does anyone know from looking (picture below) if this is integral per the comments or do I just need to work it harder?

[image: faucet removed]

Comment: This looks like a case of having to dismember  everything to remove a small part.  Those brass nuts and studs removed should help.

Comment: If it's a sink that sets on top of the counter with a bead of caulk holding it in place, disconnecting the drain pipe and cutting the caulking to remove the whole sink from the counter-top is one option.

Comment: What does the top configuration look like? Photo?

Comment: Just clarifying @crip659 comment: if the two brass nuts hold the faucet in place, then the faucet can be raised to access the connections, once the other ends of the two pipes are disconnected. And even if that *doesn't* free the faucet, then there would be more space underneath to access the connectors.

Comment: Removing the entire counter top seems a tad extreme, @Ecnerwal, no? It'll surely give room to work, but there's gotta be an easier way...

Comment: Not what I said, @FreeMan. Removing the sink from the countertop, if removing the faucet from the sink does not work out. Before the edit showing it was undermounted, and having stipulated a top mount for that approach. Removing the faucet from the sink should be pretty do-able actually, just got to loosen those brass nuts until the slotted washer will drop off.

Comment: You have created two accounts, please read the help and get them merged. And please use the original to make changes.

Answer (score 2):

Those look like integral faucet supply hoses, i.e. they are part of the faucet assembly and can not be removed. Unfixable leakage due to supply hose defect requires faucet replacement.

Comment: At least the left flexible line seems to have 3 sides of a hex nut visible above its crimped portion.

Comment: Crimp and hex are visible on both lines, but hard to access.

Comment: I can see what looks like part of a hex above the crimped part.  Still, it'll be impossible to remove without unmounting the faucet from the deck.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the entire spout from the sink (by undoing the small brass nuts on the brass studs), then you'll have plenty of room to work on it on the counter top.

They may, as kreemoweet mentioned in his answer, be integral to the spout, in which case you may have to replace the entire spout unit, or there may be bolts that you can (very inconveniently, even when it's on the counter top) be able to undo so you can replace the hose.

It's entirely possible that these hoses are bespoke for this faucet (with very small nuts at the base of the spout), so be prepared to have to purchase them from the manufacturer and not just be able to pick up a generic replacement at the big-box store.

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking of the hot or cold supply hoses that go into the spout, those are either integral to the spout and cannot be removed. ( spout needs replaced)

OR

The hoses are sealed with an o ring and once disconnected at the supply valve can just be twisted to make the seal. ( often the manufacturer cautions against overtightening.)

The best approach may be to try the hose twist ( counter clockwise) and see if this cures the leak.  If not remove the entire spout. If the hoses are removable, do so and replace the O rings. Tighten appropriately and reinstall.
If you still have a leak, replacement is the next step.

( A side note: personal experience has found that certain brands that start with a D and end with an A are especially prone to this type of failure and are best replaced with another brand.)

Answer (score 0):

Typically these flexible hoses end with a specific fitting sealed with an o-ring. Diameter, length, and screw thread may depend on what faucet you have.

[image]

Usually you screw the hoses in the faucet first, then mount it on the countertop or sink. Doing it the other way around requires a lot more cupboard yoga. So you actually disassembled it the way it was supposed to be.

If you can't unscrew the hoses from the faucet, then maybe they were mounted at the factory and locked with thread sealant. Then you have to apply a lot more force on the hex nut that goes into the faucet. If you can't pull it out, you'll have to replace everything anyway, so you can go all out.

To mount it back, get one of these faucet wrenches:

[image]